# jQuery show description div on box hover, moving title up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box of text and image, where I have  title shown all the time, but the description needs to appear only when user hovers over the box, which should move the  title up and return back to the original state when hover out.

What I want is to make sure text within box stays always vertically and horizontally center aligned, no matter how long is the description text or  title. So I was trying to use jQuery to measure the height of  title and measure the heigh of the description text to then use those numbers to increase/decrease the visible area (where text is shown).

Here is the example of the effect I want to achieve:
https://www.melinbrand.com/ (LIFESTYLE & T.E.C.H) sections.

Here is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  // GET HEIGHT ON LOAD
  $(".featured-image-box").each(function(){
      var original_title_height = $(this).find(".featured-title").height();
      var original_description_height = $(this).find(".featured-description").height();
      $(this).find(".text-area").css({
        height: original_title_height
      });

        $('.featured-image-box').hover(
            function(){
              $(this).find(".text-area").css({
                height: original_title_height + original_description_height
              })
            },
            function(){
              $(this).find(".text-area").css({
                height: original_title_height
              })
            }
        );

    });

});
```

```css
.featured-images {
  .featured-image-box {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 30vw;
    position: relative;
    @include at-query($max, $small) {
      height: 50vw;
    }
    .text-area {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      overflow: hidden;
      @include transition(all 0.3s ease-out);
      h3 {
        color: #fff;
      }
      p {
        color: #fff;
      }
      .featured-description {
        @include transition(all 0.5s ease-out);
        opacity: 0;
        a {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      }
    }
    .box-link {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      @include transition(all 0.3s ease-out);
    }
    &:hover .box-link {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    &:hover .featured-description {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid__item {{ column_width }}">
    <div class="featured-image-box" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/600/);">
      <a href="{{ block.settings.featuredsection-url }}" class="box-link"></a>
      <div class="text-area">
        <div class="featured-title">
          <h3> {{ block.settings.featuredsection-title }} </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="featured-description">
          <p>{{ block.settings.featuredsection-description }}</p>
          <span class="btn btn--small">{{ block.settings.featuredsection-linktext }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It kind of works, but the height measurements aren't correct when I hover of the image and back. Please help.

Comment: do you have to use js or would a css only solution work also?

Comment: css only: https://jsfiddle.net/pxp80k03/4/

Comment: It can be CSS only, but the example you have provided doesn't work for me as the heigh of the box has to be fixed. So when you hover over the text appear pushing title up (so it's vertically always center aligned). I don't think you can achieve that with CSS only, can you? Display: none/block doesn't work as the transition on hover is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery-UI: The Toolip widget gives some usefull options. (like [positioning](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) etc. )

More Details under https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/